# How to calculate count of related many to many objects based on another queryset?

Tags: django, django-orm

```
class Zone(Model):
  ...

class Flight(Model):
  zones = ManyToManyField(Zone)

flights = Flight.objects.filter(...)
qs1 = Zone.objects.annotate(
   count=flights.filter(zones__pk=F('pk')).distinct().count(),  # this is not valid expression
)
```

Despite having `F` inside queryset with `count()` in annotation it still throw an error `TypeError: QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): 0.` meaning that that queryset was executed in place.

Also doesn't work, but this time it just returns invalid value (always 1, always counting Zone single object instead of what inside filter):

```
qs1 = Zone.objects.annotate(
   count=Count('pk', filter=flights.filter(zones__pk=F('pk'))),  # with 'flight' instead of first 'pk' it also doesn't work
)
```

Comment: The count will immediately evaluate, so you can not use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `.count()` is evaluated *eagerly* in Django, so Django will try to evaluate the `flights.filter(zones__pk=F('pk')).distinct().count()`, and succeed to do so, since `F('pk')` will count the number of `fligts` where there are `zones` that happen to have the same primary key as the primary key of the `Flight`. You will need to use [**`OuterRef`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.OuterRef), and an `.annotate(..)` on the subquery.

But you make this too complex. You can simply annotate with:

```
from django.db.models import Q, Sum

Zone.objects.annotate(
    count=Count('flight', distinct=True, filter=Q(flight__…))
)
```

Here the `filter=Q(flight__…)` is the part of the filter of your flights. So if the `Flight`s are filtered by a hypothetical `active=True`, you filter with:

```
Zone.objects.annotate(
    count=Count('flight', distinct=True, filter=Q(flight__active=True))
)
```